# facebook login web autotriggering js script

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to embed the Facebook login functionality to grant users access to my website. My issue is that the script auto-triggers the login (and the redirect to the "/views/test_view.php") but I only want this triggered when someone clicks the facebook button.

As you can see in the code I tried to add a on-click event and override the standard function in the login button but it didn't work. 
Any ideas on how to change the script to only be executed "on click" would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
<script>
    function statusChangeCallback(response) {
        console.log('statusChangeCallback');
        console.log(response);
        // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
        // app know the current login status of the person.
        // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
        // for FB.getLoginStatus().
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            // Logged into your app and Facebook.
            testAPI();
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
                'into this app.';
        } else {
            // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
            // they are logged into this app or not.
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
                'into Facebook.';
        }
    }

    function checkLoginState() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
    }


    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: '1783721038549063',
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.6'
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response);
        });

    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
        }
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    function testAPI() {
        window.location.href = "/views/test_view.php";
    };

    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("facebook").onclick = function checkLoginState() {};

        function wait() {
            console.log("wait called");
        }
    }
</script>

<fb:login-button id="facebook" auto_logout_link=true scope="public_profile,email" size=large onlogin="wait():">
</fb:login-button>

<div id="status">
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like your `testAPI` function is doing that, and that you are calling it when the user is logged into Facebook and has connected to your app before.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

first load the FB api
them wrap everything else in the onclick listener

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                        FB.init({
                          appId      : '1783721038549063',
                          xfbml      : true,
                          version    : 'v2.6'
                        });
                     };

                    (function(d, s, id){
                        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
                        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

                    window.onload = function() {
                    document.getElementById("facebook").onclick = function checkLoginState() {
                        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                        statusChangeCallback(response);
                        }); 
                    };
                    }

                    function statusChangeCallback(response) 
                    {
                        console.log('statusChangeCallback');
                        console.log(response);
                        // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
                        // app know the current login status of the person.
                        // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
                        // for FB.getLoginStatus().
                        if (response.status === 'connected') 
                        {
                            // Logged into your app and Facebook.
                            testAPI();
                        }
                        else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') 
                        {
                        // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
                            FB.login(function(response)
                            {
                            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
                            'into this app.';
                            });
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
                            // they are logged into this app or not.
                            FB.login(function(response){
                            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
                            'into Facebook.';
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    function testAPI() {
                        window.location.href= "/views/landing_view.php";
                    }

                    </script>
```